# How in Pyhton's OOP a class's method access to another class's method?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python OOP and I am trying to learn the basics of Python OOP and I came across a video on YouTube that teaches the basics of it. The code is an example code from the video. I understood all of it but I am not able to understand how the class **"Course's"** *"get_average_grade()"* method is accessing the class **"Student's"** *"get_grade()"* method? Any help is highly appreciated.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.grade = grade # 0-100
    def get_grade(self): #<---- This method was used inside the Course class
        return self.grade

class Course:
    def __init__(self, name, max_students):
        self.name = name
        self.max_students = max_students
        self.students = [] 
    def add_student(self, student):
        if len(self.students) < self.max_students:
            self.students.append(student)
            return True 
        return False
    def get_average_grade(self):
        value = 0
        for student in self.students:
            value = value + student.get_grade() #<---- This Method is from the Student class
        return value / len(self.students)

s1 = Student("Tim", 19, 95)
s2 = Student("Bill", 19, 75)
s3 = Student("Jill", 19, 65)

course = Course("Science", 2)
course.add_student(s1)
course.add_student(s2)
```

Comment: The `student` referred to inside `Course` all are of type `Student`. Therefore they all have the `get_grade` method that's in the `Student` class.

Comment: So, the type of the **class Student** and type of obj **s1** both are `__main__.Student` , am I correct?

Comment: yes and `add.student` is adding `s1` to `self.students` which is a list of students stored in the course object. (you can access it via `print(course.students)`

Comment: @Nash_per reply to your comment. No the type of class Student is not __main__.Student.  You can use type(Student) to show what it is.

Comment: @MiloChen, thanks for pointing it out! But now I am a bit lost, `Student` is a Class type that makes sense, but then how come from list **student** is passing its values `([("Tim", 19, 95), ("Bill", 19, 75)])` to the `get_grade()` method that is in another class without inheriting the class?

Comment: @studioj, thank you for your reply, Yes `print(course.students)` gives me this ->`[<__main__.Student object at 0x000001B0DA6E0970>]`,  but my question is how python is doing this? Because I did not inherit the `Student`  class, but I have access to its methods, so I am not getting how I am able to call methods of a class from another class without inheriting it.

Comment: Hi @Nash_per, when you use s1 = Student("Tim", 19, 95)
The function __init__(self, name, age, grade) will be called. This function set age and grade for the instance s1.  the course instance add s1 by call add_student(s1).

Comment: @Nash_per furthermore, The list students is members of course instance. s1 will be an element in the list students. 
So you can get s1 instance by get course.students[some_idx] after you add s1 into this list by calling course.add_student(s1)

Comment: @Nash_per. Welcome to the Magic of object oriented programming :-). Maybe this link can get you a larger explanation https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/ it is well written, complete and relatively simple to read and understand